# Crazy hard; essentially futile?

Tags: word, knowledge, connections-puzzle

Who do you associate with these words/sounds?:

- Oath
- [This sound](https://soundcloud.com/user-442192927/beep#t=0:01)
- Hell (as a name for something)
- Scoff
- Cuisine

The answer is a (fairly well-known) person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's

> Gordon Ramsay

Oath

> As in "sworn" - Wordplay on swearing, as in offensive language (which he is known for)

Bleep sound

> Censoring the offensive language he's known for

Hell

> His show Hell's Kitchen

Scoff

> 1) Scoff as in mock, 2) scoff as in eating greedily (british) 3) (clarified by OP) scoff can also simply mean food (british)

Cuisine

> Well, he's a chef

The title: Crazy hard; essentially futile?

> First letters spell "Chef"

Comment: How the **** did you get that so fast. Amazing. As a sidenote, *scoff* also means *food*, and *cuisine* means *kitchen*.

Comment: Seemed fairly intuitive. Yeah, I didn't mention that meaning of cuisine so I can sneak in a "duh" comment ;) Will add that second def of scoff to the answer, thanks! I admittedly had to google other definitions of scoff (and food didn't immediately come up) since that was the clue I didn't fully get :)

Comment: Google swearing, hell and food... I have to be honest your last puzzle was waaaayyyy too hard without hints, this one is very easy, somewhere inbetween would be ideal.